# What is the difference between Snowflake connectors and drivers?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake has Node.js driver, Go driver, .NET driver, JDBC, ODBC **driver**, and Python **connector**. To me, these connectors/drivers seem to do the same things, they provide *similar* interfaces for developing applications in different languages.

Why does Snowflake need to use different terms for the same things? Is there any difference between connectors and drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fundamental difference between the use of the `connector` and `driver` words among Snowflake's [varied client software](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/conns-drivers.html).

The [snowflake-connector-python](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python) project naming in particular appears to mirror the [pre-existing mysql-connector-python naming style](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html#idm45135527034048) used by the MySQL Developers. Like it, the Snowflake offering also offers a [DB-API spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) implementation.

The python connector does offer more than just the DB-API spec, [with APIs that ease use of Pandas as an example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html), but that does not appear to be why it was named as a `connector` instead of a `driver`. History is also an influence here, with the Python connector name [likely preceding all others](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/commit/3edaa6d2dde6dba68d93dcf448a328b31364ad36).

The name choices appear to be inertia or standard driven (named after a prior offering, or after the standard `driver` naming [such as from ODBC's history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity#Drivers_and_Managers)), or simply driven by zeitgeist (named after other popular projects in its space during its launch).